# is there an easy way to make codes in qt creator(minGW) work in VS2015(msvc)?

Tags: qt, visual-c++, mingw

I use  menu"QT5-->open **.pro"to load .pro file(coded in qt creator using minGW compiler) ino VS2015;
so many syntactic error;
and i dont know how to fix it !
should i create a new project in VS2015,and copy my codes in VS? -.-

Comment: they are different formats: but some search engine magic helps: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-platform-notes.html#creating-visual-studio-project-files

Comment: yeah,I import the .pro file but  dont know how to do with many syntactic errors ;